# Is there any nanosecond-class time function on unix?

Tags: unix, unix-timestamp

I just have a performance test on a lib, maybe some operation is nanosecond-class, so I wonder if there is any function can do such thing, thank you for paying attention.

Comment: How do you know I'm paying attention?

Comment: oh, I don't know, it's just a broadcast....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need nano precision then you probably want [HPET](http://blog.fpmurphy.com/2009/07/linux-hpet-support.html) and the [`clock_gettime()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/clock_gettime.html). First link even has some sample code to get you started with a nice explanation of the linux hpet support.

Comment: I found that the last three digits of the tv_nsec is always 000 in CentOS, do you know why?

Comment: Unfortunately I have not used centOS yet. Does your hardware have a HPET? Can it be a bug if you are using an older release?